# C# DateTime and String value condition check

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have a problem.

This is not working

> ```
> > var from = "";
> > StartDTime = Convert.ToDateTime(from);
> ```

This is working

> ```
> > var from = "2021-10-05";
> > StartDTime = Convert.ToDateTime(from);
> ```

Some time I'm sending Date Value, but sometime in not sending Date Value.in that time `from` variable pass as a empty string. I want to set if from variable is = "" then need to set default Date Value.so how can I resolve this?. Please help me guys. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried [DateTime.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse) ?

Comment: Try `DateTime StartDTime = DateTime.TryParse(from, out StartDTime) ? StartDTime : DateTime.Now;`

Comment: `from` is a [contextual keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/#contextual-keywords). It is probably a good idea to totally avoid keywords as variable names though, given the context, it will compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A safe way of doing that would be:

```
StartDTime = string.IsNullOrEmpty(from) ? DateTime.Now : DateTime.Parse(from);
```

But if you have control over the code passing the "from" variable, you can declare it as nullable DateTime, then your code would look like this:

```
DateTime? from = null;
var StartDTime = from.HasValue ? from.Value : DateTime.Now;
```

Which for short would be:

```
StartDTime = from ?? DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: What would happen if `from` is not a string that can be parsed to a date?, like `from = "abcd";` in your code.

Comment: @VDWWD it would error, I don't like Wilson's solution here

Comment: The premise of the question is tha the "from" variable is either empty string or a date value.
Unless the developer consider other possible values.... more code than that is just polluting the codebase.

Comment: True, but it's better to err on the side of safer code.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime.TryParse will do the job for you:
for example:

```
    DateTime dateTime;
    var from = ""; 
    DateTime.TryParse(from, out dateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner, with only the validation you specify:

```
StartDTime = from == "" ? new DateTime() : Convert.ToDateTime(from);
```

Comment: What would happen if `from` is not a string that can be parsed to a date?, like `from = "abcd";` in your code.

Comment: Well, a probably not-so desireable exception would be thrown. Hence my note, with _only_ the validation the questioner specified.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert` methods either successfully convert the string passed to it, or throws an error, that's the way it's supposed to work. For most data types there are also `TryParse` methods that return true/false based on if it converted successfully and have an output variable which will be `DateTime.MinValue` if it failed. This is how I would handle your situation:

```
DateTime startDTime;
string from = "";
if (!DateTime.TryParse(from, out startDTime)){
    startDTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

This will set the startTime to the date passed in from, but if no date was passed it sets it to the current date and time - if you want a different default value, that replaces `new DateTime()` and if your default should be January 1, 0001, then you can just use the TryParse part directly, since that's the automatic default for a failed TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ellegant, but works.

```
var from = "";
if(from == ""){ from = DateTime.MinValue.ToString(); }
DateTime StartDTime = Convert.ToDateTime(from);
```

But i think that a nullable DateTime would be more elegant, like this:

```
var from = null;
DateTime? StartDTime = from;
```

Or you can set a default date, like this:

```
var from = null;
DateTime? StartDTime = from ?? YourDefaultDate;
```

Comment: Thank you for you support